# Why use IoC / DI if concrete classes are known?

Tags: design-patterns, dependency-injection, inversion-of-control

I have been reading for several days now on Dependency Injection / Inversion of Control and am struggling to understand a concept.

Lets assume I have the following *trivial* scenario:

```
public interface ILocation
{
    string LocationName { get; set; }
}

// The implementation / concrete class for ILocation
public class Location : ILocation
{
    public string LocationName {
        get { /* logic */ }
        set { /* logic */ }
    }
}


// My class that depends on ILocation as a dependency
public class SomeClass{
    public SomeClass(ILocation location)
    {
        this.theLocation = location;
    }

    // 
    // more code...
    // 
}
```

Great, so I get my `ILocation` injected into my `SomeClass`... but I had to wire up `ILocation` to be handled by `Location` within my Dependency Injection framework IN CODE and compile that. (Aside: I realize that there are frameworks that do this configuration in files, i.e. XML config files)

What is the point of creating this "separation" of knowledge when all the components listed above are necessary to exist at compile time?

This is really racking me. Perhaps I've missed the point entirely. Now, that being said, I do see a lot of people talk about "testability" and I can see the advantage there, but let's assume we're throwing testing out the window; what else are the advantages? What is this *really* giving me?

I originally sought out this concept to learn more in hopes that I could find a good way to design a "plugin" pattern for an application I'm building. So far, this appears as though it would not work for the concept of runtime plugins.

Looking forward to insight on the subject - Thank you!

Comment: Testability is the biggest benefit, and it is not a trivial one.  I wouldn't "throw it out the window.".

Comment: If `Location` is just a data container (no behavior), there is typically no reason to abstract it. In general, interfaces are for abstracting behavior, not data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take your class and get rid of DI.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private Location _location = new Location();
    public SomeClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Great, you are able to create the Location object and it takes in no parameters in its constructor.  Code is looking pretty, and it was easy right?  But wait, there is now a change to the Location class that requires it's own dependency, LocationFinder.  So we add that to the object construction, and maybe we move it to the constructor.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private Location _location;
    public SomeClass()
    {
         _location = new Location(new LocationFinder());
    }
}
```

Ok, less pretty but still not too bad.  But sure enough 6 months later LocationFinder has to change and now it needs to be created from a factory, LocationFinderFactory, which has its own dependencies.

```
public class SomeClass
{
    private Location _location;
    public SomeClass()
    {
        var locationFinderFactory = new LocationFinderFactory(new LocationFinderStrategy());
        _location = new Location(locationFinderFactory.Create());
    }
}
```

Not quite as clean not right?  The more noteworthy point is that everytime the Location implementation changed you had to change the SomeClass as well.  **You've coupled the implementation of SomeClass to Location and 3 other classes as well!**  Now you will be changing SomeClass everytime any of the these 4 classes has to change.

Moral of the story, code your classes in a loosely coupled way (such as using DI) and these type of code changes will be localized to only the classes that it should affect.

Comment: Is your point, that you offload the responsibility of the creation of your required object to a central location? If so, (to play devil's advocate) couldn't your required class just offer static methods to coordinate its instantiation? If you referenced that method i.e. `Location.RetrieveLocation()` and centralized all the complexities in there, then in essence you've cut out the concern you've illustrated. Thank you very much for your thoughts on the subject. Any additional info would be appreciated!

Comment: Yes, you could do that, but than you are making changes to the Location class anytime it's dependencies change.  You've moved the dependencies from one class to another, in essence you've shuffled the dependencies when you want to remove them.   If you use an IOC container for your DI you wouldn't even have to write the code for the static method.  It is all configuration.  Plus you get the other benefit of testability.  :)

Answer (score 2):

Dependency injection's first goal is to make the code easily unit-testable.

Then come additional advantages, like the possibility to inject proxies (AOP, used for transactions, security checks, etc.), to configure the injected components, to choose implementations depending on a profile or configuration, etc. All this depends on the capabilities of your framework.

Comment: I'm using .Net and my framework has yet to be determined (if used at all). Thanks for the response, JB!

Answer (score 1):

What you're gaining is separation of concerns.   With DI, you can freely change the implementation or swap out implementations of the `ILogger` *without* having to modify (or even recompile) `SomeClass`.  With DI, `SomeClass` doesn't care what class is implementing the `ILogger` interface, as long as it implements all the methods in the interface.  If you used concrete classes, if you wanted to change which class was implementing the methods, you would have to modify `SomeClass` as well.  With DI, all you have to change is what class is getting sent to the constructor, or the configuration of the IoC container, without having to modify `SomeClass` itself.

Comment: This then lends the question: How do you change out your ILogger implementation without recompiling? Additionally, if all these items are in the same project (as a requirement that I see listed above due to DI and how it *appears* to work to me), why does it matter if you can swap out the class? I can simply refactor the code to point to a new class that satisfies the same requirements of the original class. The new class would have abide by the same interface as the original, thus the work would have to be put in SOMEWHERE, just changing the *where*. This is how I understand it, am I off?

Comment: "How do you change out your ILogger implementation without recompiling?"  Factory class, if/else logic, IOC container configuration, etc.

Comment: @Ryan Griffith "Additionally, if all these items are in the same project (as a requirement that I see listed above due to DI and how it appears to work to me)"  This isn't a requirement of any sort to use DI.

Comment: @RyanGriffith  "I can simply refactor the code to point to a new class that satisfies the same requirements of the original class"  Sure, but you can't do it an runtime which is critical for many problems, unit testing to name one.

Comment: @RyanGriffith *"Additionally, if all these items are in the same project (as a requirement that I see listed above due to DI and how it appears to work to me)"* I've never seen an IoC container that imposes this kind of restriction.

Comment: Let me clarify this sentence: "Additionally, if all these items are in the same project (as a requirement that I see listed above due to DI and how it appears to work to me)". I'm using both platform specific terminology (.Net) and incorrect terminology at the same time. What I mean to say is, the concrete class must be available at compile time and within my "Solution"'s scope. I have to wire-up my bindings `Bind<IService>().To<ServiceImpl>();` within my project for my IoC container. Thanks for the feedback :)

Comment: @RyanGriffith I can see how that would be perceived as a limitation (examples of DI often look like this). In reality it's not so common to configure dependencies this way. Most IoC containers have the ability to scan assemblies/directories and automatically wire-up dependencies based on naming conventions. See [this structuremap example](http://docs.structuremap.net/ScanningAssemblies.htm).

Answer (score 0):

The way you manage dependencies inside your system have a huge impact on the quality of your software (flexibility, robustness, reusability, maintability) especially in the long run when your system goes through a lot of changes as time goes by.
And dependency injection is one powerful tool (among others) to manage dependencies.

This article discusses this topic beautifully, so I don't try to replicate it :) http://www.objectmentor.com/resources/articles/Principles_and_Patterns.pdf